# Questions about TDD

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, architecture, tdd, mocking

### Environment

In my solution I have three projects, they are:

1. Web (Asp.net MVC4)
2. Model (Class library)
3. Test (Test project)

In **Model project** have:

`Couple` = Class

`IRepository` = Interface-based repository

`ICoupleRepository` = Interface Repository couple

`Implementation` repository = CoupleRepository couple

In **Test project** have:

Fake/`CoupleRepository` = Fake implementation of Repository couple  (inside the folder Fake).
`CoupleTest` couple class = Test

### Behavior

By adding a couple under, need to modify some properties and also add a couple object also add other objects to the database.

I put this logic into the `CoupleRepository` (not fake) repository in `Add` method, I set these properties, add the object couple and two other objects.

```
public class CoupleRepository : ICoupleRepository
{
    public void Add(Couple couple)
    {
        couple.Bride.Gender = Gender.Female;
        couple.Groom.Gender = Gender.Male;
        db.Couples.Add(couple);

        db.Users.Add(new User{ CoupleID = couple.Bride.ID });
        db.Users.Add(new User{ CoupleID = couple.Groom.ID });
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

### Question

In my test class, `CoupleTest`, need to test the addition of these users as well, and the modification of the properties.

Create a fake repository for my forehead it will not help me, really need to test code that is in default CoupleRepository.

What is the **tip you give me**?

Where **Mocks and Stubs come in all this?**

Where **would this logic to save a couple?**

I have to test repositories? Perhaps the ideal would be to **test the controllers?**

Many questions, I know =)

---

I'm new to TDD and do not know if I'm going in the right direction.

Test the default repository would not be ideal, since it accesses the database.

Comment: if it was actually TDD wouldn't you be writing unit tests first?

Comment: I *think* that your fake implementations are your mocks.  You're just not calling them that.  To be really useful mocks however, you'd want to be able to tell them to behave in certain ways so that you can test different behaviors.

Comment: @DavidWick yup, what you said. If he's not starting with the tests, he's not doing Test *Driven* Development at all.

Comment: In fact this is the only implementation. I know I did wrong but do not know where to begin testing. The question is **where to put this implementation and how to test it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue here is that you mix different layers. Repository is a intermediate level between Business Logic and storage. If your case, repository performs actions which are the part of Business logic. That's why you're forced to mimic that in your tests.

In general your entity should be fully constructed prior to saving. Repository should only save it (probably, invoking Validate method, if you need that).

This code:

```
couple.Bride.Gender = Gender.Female;
couple.Groom.Gender = Gender.Male;
```

should be moved to Couple business logic (constructor, for example).

From the more global point of view, with TDD you make mocks *around* the functionality you want to test. With your current approach you'll probably have something like `IView -> Couple class -> IRepository` chain. That means that by mocking those interfaces, you intend to test Couple class (or business logic work in general).

To test the repository, you need a structure like `Couple class -> CoupleRepository -> IDatabaseDriver` sequence. By mocking `IDatabaseDriver` you'll be able to verify SqlCommands or Queries generated by real implementation of CoupleRepository.

In that case you'll write tests like (very simplistic sample):

```
var driver = new  MockDatabaseDriver();
var repo = CoupleRepository(MockDatabaseDriver);
repo.Add(new Couple());
Assert.AreEquals("Insert into COUPLES values ('bride', groom')", driver.SqlQueryText);
```

Here MockDatabaseDriver doesn't execute queries, just indicates actions performed by repository.